# retrieve max date results

Tags: sql

Table A

```
Group   ID  
1      117  
2     123  
3     117
```

Table B

```
Group ID    Date  
1     120   18/2/2  
1     113   18/2/3  
1     123   18/2/4  
2     113   18/1/1  
2     120   18/4/5  
2     123   18/7/6   
3     113   18/1/1  
3     120   18/4/5  
3     123   18/2/3
```

I want to retrieve all those rows where Id in table A = 117 and its corresponding entry in Table B with ID = 123 and if it has maximum date
Result should be :
1  123 18/2/4

Comment: Your question is unclear a bit, could you please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53109840/edit)** your question and add expected resutlts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT MIN(T1.[Group]) [Group],
       T1.ID,
       T2.ID,
       MAX(T2.[Date]) [Date]
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.[Group] = T2.[Group]
WHERE T1.ID = 117
      AND
      T2.ID = 123
GROUP BY T1.ID,
         T2.ID;
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------+-----+-----+---------------------+
| Group | ID  | ID  |        Date         |
+-------+-----+-----+---------------------+
|     1 | 117 | 123 | 04/02/2018 00:00:00 |
+-------+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.Group ,T2.ID, T2.Date 
From TableA as T1 INNER JOIN TableB as T2
ON T1.GroupId = T2.GroupId 
WHERE T2.Date = (SELECT MAX(T2.Date))
```

Can you try this query, it's basically joining two tables with your GroupID as it's relationship between those tables, and after that it's selecting MAX date value from your second table, and in your select you specify what you want to see.

Because you said you want to see Group from first table, ID from second table and Max date from Second table there it is..

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH subq AS (
    SELECT b.id, MAX(b.date) mx_date
    FROM b
    INNER JOIN a ON b.group = a.group
    WHERE a.id = 117 AND b.id = 123
    GROUP BY b.id
)
SELECT b.group, s.id, s.mx_date
FROM subq s
INNER JOIN b ON s.id = b.id and s.mx_date = b.date
```

Here's my solution.

- Join tables a and b
- Filter by a.id = 117 and b.id = 123
- Group by b.id and select max(date)
- Join back onto b to select the group

Answer (score 0):

First you have wrong `Date Format` in your `TableB` and i am wonder is this format in `date` type column, if no then it would become trouble.

If this already format in `date` type column then you can try this query

```
SELECT 
     TA.Group, 
     TB.ID, 
     TB.Max_Date 
FROM 
     TableA as TA 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                    GROUP, 
                    ID, 
                    MAX(DATE) AS Max_Date
                 FROM
                    TableB
                 WHERE
                    ID = '123'
                 GROUP BY
                    GROUP,
                    ID) TB ON TA.Group = TB.Group
WHERE
     TA.ID = 117
```

And for the Worst Case you in `Date` column not `Date Format`. You can try this.

```
    SELECT 
         TA.Group, 
         TB.ID, 
         TB.Max_Date 
    FROM 
         TableA as TA 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                        GROUP, 
                        ID, 
                        MAX(To_Date(DATE, 'YY/MM/DD')) AS Max_Date
                     FROM
                        TableB
                     WHERE
                        ID = '123'
                     GROUP BY
                        GROUP,
                        ID) TB ON TA.Group = TB.Group
    WHERE
         TA.ID = 117
```

I am using `To_Date` function in `Postgresql` because i don't know what `rdbms` you are using..

Comment: Hi, the above query is retrieving all those rows where Id in table A = 117 and its corresponding entry in Table B with ID = 123 and its  maximum date in Table B. But i want to retrieve the record where Id in table A = 117 and its corresponding entry in Table B with ID = 123  only if it has maximum date

Comment: @Cherry what type in `date` column? and what `rdbms` you are using here?

Comment: date is correct for first option not in Date format and i am using SQL

Comment: @Cherry sql are language not database.. Database like postgresql, mysql, oracle.. So which one you using?